# Why JWT length is exceed ? can we handle it?

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

This is my code to generate JWT.

```
//create security token handler
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
//create byte array of token key
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenKey);
//create token descriptor
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
     Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]{
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username),
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,myrole),
     new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,myemail) }),
 
     NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
     SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
     new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
 };
 var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
 var JWTtoken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);   // this is my JWT.
```

Above code generated access token for me I can use it to access server resources.
When I want to refresh the the token I used claims to generate new JWT.

Here is my code for refresh/generate new JWT.

```
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tokenKey);
var principle = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token.Value,
new TokenValidationParameters()
{
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
      ValidateIssuer = false,
      ValidateAudience = false,
      ValidateLifetime = false
  }, out validatedToken);
```

Above code validate my expired token and returns principle.
I used claims in this principle to generate new JWT.

```
var jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            claims: principle.Claims.ToArray(),
            notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                                new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                                SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
            );

 var newToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);
```

Length of this new token is exceeds than previous token.

```
 length of first token is 297
 length of new token is 516
```

I observed
claim names in new token is changes to web address in payload.

Claims in first token

```
 "unique_name": "user1",
 "role": "Admin",
 "email": "Email",
```

Claims in new token

```
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name": "user1",
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": "Admin",
"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress": "Email"
```

Comment: change in Claim type name exceed the length of token. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: I never said I have bug or error and not mention anywhere about any bug. just want suggestions how to handle this situation.  And thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft and OAuth/OpenIDConnect have different opinions on what the claim names should be, so when your .NET code receives a token, then it will rename some of the claims automatically.

One way to disable this mapping is to clear the map using:

```
// By default, Microsoft has some legacy claim mapping that converts
// standard JWT claims into proprietary ones. This removes those mappings.
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

This renaming of claims is something you have to be aware of and this is not a bug. Its just a fact of life that you have to accept and work around.

Comment: Thank you @Tore Nestenius.  Using this lines of code I can generate fix length JWT.